# Producing Avro type message in spark sql 2.4.4 data frame to Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to write Avro messages into Kafka in spark SQL. Can someone suggest me how to implement it in java? I found a scala reference code but not Java.

I tried it but throwing error and where can I configure the schema registry.

```
aggr.selectExpr("CAST(order_id AS String) AS key", "to_avro(struct(*)) AS value").write().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("topic", "aggr_topic").save();
```

or please replicate scala code to java .

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaURL)
  .option("subscribe", "t")
  .load()
  .select(
    from_avro($"key", "t-key", schemaRegistryURL).as("key"),
    from_avro($"value", "t-value", schemaRegistryURL).as("value"))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That code is the exact same in Java, with the exception of `val df`

`from_avro` only exists in databricks environment, by the way, and you want `writeStream` and `to_avro`, anyway.

The alternative is to convert the dataframe into RDD with foreachPartition, then create a new KafkaProducer manually to send events

You might also be interested in https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS